Recargar elementos del DOM via JS o JQUERY
alguien sabe como puedo hacer para que despues de terminar una actualizacion via modal pueda recargar elementos del dom sin necesidad de recargar la pagina?
ejemplo:


 $("#editzact-form").ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {

    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data['estado'] == 'error') {
            alerta('error', data['salida']);
        } else {
            alerta('exito', data['salida']);
            $('#modalEditActualizacion').modal('hide');
            //AQUI QUIRO ACTUALIZAR
            $('#root').reload();
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('Error: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);

    }
});



donde no quiero usar innerHtml, .html, .append para insertar lo nuevo actualizado solo que se haga un reload al elemento porque ya php mostrara lo nuevo actualizado por medio de echo

Prueba con el código siguiente:
...
//AQUI QUIERO ACTUALIZAR
$('#root').load(location.href + " #root>*", "");
...

Esto recargará los elementos hijos de #root sin necesidad de recargar toda la página.

Genial si lo hace pero veo que me quita los tooltips quizas tenga que volver a inicializar o puede haber otro problema con los scr de mis archivos?

Sí, tienes que volver a inicializarlos después de la recarga.

Listo con esto quedo:
$('#root').load(location.href + " #root>*", function(){
$('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.
